# Error in In App Purchase: Parental Controls are enabled

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, in-app-purchase

I want to implement In App Purchase in my iPhone app.

I have done all the steps and I have added following code on viewWillAppear of my viewController, but it doesnt satisfy the condition `canMakePayments` and always executes the `else` part.

What could be wrong?

```
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
    NSLog(@"Parental-controls are disabled");

    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.dev.InAppTry"]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Parental-controls are enabled");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying this in the simulator?

Comment: @rckoenes: Thanks for the input. No I am trying this on my device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable Parental Control in setting in Device.

Setting --> General --> Restrictions.

Do Disable Restriction or In Allowed Content section : Make In app purchase=ON.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Are there other methods? This didn't work for me. I created a sandbox user with birth date 1/1/80. Also, I explicitly enabled in-app purchases in Settings/Restrictions. Still the system presents a dialog to ask mom for the purchase.